# Extend controller that extending base controller in laravel and use in router

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am working on laravel 6. I have an controller ABController which extends AbBaseController.
Now AbBaseController extends laravel's Controller which we do normally in every controller.
I have a method called index in ABController
eg

```
Class ABController extends AbBaseController {
    public function index() {
         // some index code
    }
}
```

Now i want to use index method using router.php file as

```
Router::get('/index', 'ABController@index');
```

While debugging route worked as

```
Router::get('/index', function(){ echo 'in'; });
```

i get proper output.. But when controller is replaced, ABController is not getting called.
Can any body help me out . Is there any way to deal with it.

Comment: what is happening when you go to this 'index' route?

Comment: @lagbox giving 500 internal server error

Comment: okay check the logs to find out why you are getting a 500 error ...